# Options in a StringReplace rule

Tags: string-manipulation, options

- case1

  ```
  Options[f] = {"t" -> "0"};
  f[___, OptionsPattern[]] :=  StringReplace["content", "t" :> OptionValue["t"]]

  f[]

  (*
  con0en0
  *)
  ```
- case2

  ```
  rule = {"t" -> OptionValue["t1"]};

  Options[gg] = {"t1" -> "T1", "t2" -> "1"};
  gg[___, OptionsPattern[]] := StringReplace["content", rule]

  gg[1]

  (*
  con~~OptionValue[t1]~~en~~OptionValue[t1]
  *)
  ```

Here `OptionValue` couldn't get the value of "t1"
So, how to make case 2 works like case 1?

---

I found one solution is

```
Options[gg]={"t1"->"T1","t2"->"1"};
gg[___,OptionsPattern[]]:=Hold[StringReplace]["content",rule]//ReleaseHold//Evaluate
```

Any simpler methods?

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you outlined you intended use of this behavior, as without that it is not clear what is and is not helpful.

#### Single function case

You can use the two-argument form of `OptionValue`:

```
rule = {"t" :> OptionValue[gg, "t1"]};  (* note RuleDelayed *)

Options[gg] = {"t1" -> "T1", "t2" -> "1"};
gg[___, OptionsPattern[]] := StringReplace["content", rule]

gg[1]
```

> ```
> "conT1enT1"
> ```

This works just fine with a single function (`gg`), but it is not directly applicable if you intend to use this rule in multiple functions.

#### Arbitrary function case

As you apparently understand based on your workaround, the single-argument `OptionValue` expression must appear literally on the right-hand-side of a rule or definition with `OptionsPattern`, which your use of `Evaluate` does.  Any other method that does the same can be used, e.g.:

```
With[{rule = rule},
  gg[___, OptionsPattern[]] := StringReplace["content", rule]
]
```

Or:

```
(gg[___, OptionsPattern[]] := StringReplace["content", #]) & @ rule
```

For the arbitrary-function case I see no simpler method than these.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not what you are after:

```
op[] := Function[x, 
   x /. MapThread[
     Rule[#1, (#2)] &, {{"t", "t1", "t2"}, 
      Thread["t" -> {"0", "T1", "1"}]}]];
srf[opts_: "t"] := StringReplace["content", op[][opts]]
```

Note:

```
srf[]
```

yields the default value:

"con0en0"

```
srf/@{"t","t1","t2"}
```

yields

{"con0en0", "conT1enT1", "con1en1"}

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to keep `OptionValue` inside the function :-

```
rule = {"t" -> "t1"};

Options[gg] = {"t1" -> "T1", "t2" -> "1"};
gg[___, OptionsPattern[]] := StringReplace["content", #1 -> OptionValue[#2] & @@@ rule]

gg[1]
```

> "conT1enT1"